# Classify an image using Bag of Words dictionary of different training classes

Tags: c++, opencv, sift

I am creating Bag of Words dictionary using SIFT (OpenCV) like this:

```
    char * filename = new char[100];
    Mat input;
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
    Mat descriptor;
    Mat featuresUnclustered;
    SiftDescriptorExtractor detector;

    int totalIamgesToTrain = 200;

    for (int f = 1; f <= totalIamgesToTrain; f++) {
        sprintf(filename, "/path_to_training_images/%i.png", f);
        input = imread(filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
        detector.detect(input, keypoints);
        detector.compute(input, keypoints, descriptor);
        featuresUnclustered.push_back(descriptor);
    }

    int dictionarySize = totalIamgesToTrain;
    TermCriteria tc(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 0.001);
    BOWKMeansTrainer bowTrainer(dictionarySize, tc, 1, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS);
    Mat dictionary = bowTrainer.cluster(featuresUnclustered);
    FileStorage fs("dictionary1.yml", FileStorage::WRITE); //assume creating total 5 dictionaries like this.
    fs << "vocabulary" << dictionary;
    fs.release();
```

I am using this [image datasets](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/Image_Datasets/Caltech256/images/).

I am obtaining BoF descriptor of a given image like this:

```
    Mat dictionary;
    FileStorage fs("dictionary1.yml", FileStorage::READ);
    fs["vocabulary"] >> dictionary;
    fs.release();

    Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher(new FlannBasedMatcher);
    Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector(new SiftFeatureDetector());
    Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractor(new SiftDescriptorExtractor);
    BOWImgDescriptorExtractor bowDE(extractor, matcher);
    bowDE.setVocabulary(dictionary); //setting the loaded dictionary

    char * filename = new char[100];
    FileStorage fs1("result1.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);

    sprintf(filename, "/path_to_image/query.png");
    Mat img = imread(filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
    detector->detect(img, keypoints);

    Mat bowDescriptor;
    bowDE.compute(img, keypoints, bowDescriptor);

    fs1 << "result" << bowDescriptor;
    fs1.release();
```

Similarly, I am detecting the given (query)image on all the 5 dictionaries and getting 5 different results.
Now, how do I get the best category the given (query)image among all 5 classes?

Comment: Count how many times each category is found by testing on your different dictionaries, and consider the "most founded category" as the correct one. If all are different for a given image, you should consider to classify the given image as clutter (not belonging to any of the category you have).

Comment: Why you need 5 dictionaries?

Comment: how do I compare the results? Say I have 5 results for a particular image tested on the 5 dictionaries.

Comment: @Miki, 5 dictionaries is an example.

Comment: 5 results means that your image is classified as belonging to a class by each dictionary. Suppose your classified classes are (A,B,A,A,C), you can classify your image as A (the "most founded category"). If your classification result is (A,B,C,D,E) you can assume that your image doesn't belong to any of these, an so classify it as clutter

Comment: yeah, I got that 5 is an example. But why you need _multiple_ dictionaries?

Comment: The dictionary should be one. You build your dictionary with all SIFT extracted from ALL your images. Then you build an histogram (accorging to this dictionary) for all images in each class. The you compute the histogram of your query image on the dictionary, and compare with the histogram for each class. The most similar histogram is your classified class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83340/discussion-between-rohit-arya-and-miki).